# android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #15: Error inflating class com.example.studentjob.CustomSpinner

Tags: android, android-spinner

I am trying to create custom **Spinner** in my App. But It is through below error.

I am unable to find out where I did mistake. Please any one can help me out.

Thanks,
Giwit

Exception:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(367): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-10 17:54:39.828: E/AndroidRuntime(367): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.studentjob/com.example.studentjob.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #15: Error inflating class com.example.studentjob.CustomSpinner
03-10 17:54:39.828: E/AndroidRuntime(367):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2295)
03-10 17:54:39.828: E/AndroidRuntime(367):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2349)
03-10 17:54:39.828: E/AndroidRuntime(367):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:159)
03-10 17:54:39.828: E/AndroidRuntime(367):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1316)
03-10 17:54:39.828: E/AndroidRuntime(367):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-10 17:54:39.828: E/AndroidRuntime(367):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-10 17:54:39.828: E/AndroidRuntime(367):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
03-10 17:54:39.828: E/AndroidRuntime(367):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-10 17:54:39.828: E/AndroidRuntime(367):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
03-10 17:54:39.828: E/AndroidRuntime(367):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1187)
03-10 17:54:39.828: E/AndroidRuntime(367):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
03-10 17:54:39.828: E/AndroidRuntime(367):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-10 17:54:39.828: E/AndroidRuntime(367): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #15: Error inflating class com.example.studentjob.CustomSpinner
03-10 17:54:39.828: E/AndroidRuntime(367):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:626)
03-10 17:54:39.828: E/AndroidRuntime(367):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:702)
03-10 17:54:39.828: E/AndroidRuntime(367):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761)
03-10 17:54:39.828: E/AndroidRuntime(367):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498)
03-10 17:54:39.828: E/AndroidRuntime(367):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
03-10 17:54:39.828: E/AndroidRuntime(367):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354)
03-10 17:54:39.828: E/AndroidRuntime(367):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:361)
03-10 17:54:39.828: E/AndroidRuntime(367):  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1956)
03-10 17:54:39.828: E/AndroidRuntime(367):  at com.example.studentjob.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:11)
03-10 17:54:39.828: E/AndroidRuntime(367):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5372)
03-10 17:54:39.828: E/AndroidRuntime(367):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1104)
03-10 17:54:39.828: E/AndroidRuntime(367):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2257)
```

Comment: Please edit the question and post full exception stacktrace and relevant code.

Comment: activity_main.xml:
    <com.example.studentjob.CustomSpinner
        android:id="@+id/sp_gender"
        style="@style/common_edittext_style"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dip"
        android:layout_below="@id/tv_title"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:hint="@string/text_hint_gender" />

Comment: Your activity code and your CustomSpinner code

Comment: Mainactyvity.java:                                                                
package com.example.studentjob;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Fragment;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  CustomSpinner spGender = (CustomSpinner)findViewById(R.id.sp_gender);
  spGender.setItems(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.gender_array));
  //spGender.setSelectedPosition(0);
 }

}

Comment: Please, post the XML layout and code.

Comment: @GiwitUser not as a comments edit your question and post..

Comment: There should be even more stacktrace. "Error inflating class" exceptions always have a nested inner exception which is relevant in diagnosing the issue.

Comment: Thanks For your replay I am posted my  java code and xml code in above comments.

Comment: post your `CustomSpinner` class also...

Comment: It is not allowing to post my code can you suggest me where I need to post My java class